# PyQt4: Items disappear when using Drag and Drop with QComboBox

Tags: drag-and-drop, qt4, pyqt4, qcombobox

I would like to use drag-and-drop to rearrange the items in a QComboBox. I tried this:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QComboBox, QAbstractItemView

a = QApplication([''])
c = QComboBox()
c.addItem('a')
c.addItem('b')
c.addItem('c')
c.addItem('d')

view = c.view()
view.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)

c.show()
c.raise_()

a.exec_()
```

However, dragging an item on top of another item deletes the dragged item -- I want that item to be moved above/below the drop location. Am I doing this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each combo item needs to be disabled as a drop target by setting the appropriate [item flags](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.8-snapshot/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum).

Here's one way to achieve that:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
combo = QtGui.QComboBox()

model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
for text in 'One Two Three Four'.split():
    item = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
    item.setFlags(item.flags() & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled)
    model.appendRow(item)

combo.setModel(model)
combo.view().setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
combo.show()

app.exec_()
```